# VPN vs. DoH or both?

Tags: vpn, doh

I have set my Mac system WiFi DNS to 1.1.1.1. and I believe Safari supports DoH now.

Should I use **both** DoH and a VPN together? Is using both better or does using both decrease security in any way?

Comment: Welcome on Security SE, could you please explain a little more what you would like to achieve and how.

Comment: I'm a little embarrassed  - Sorry about how simplistic this question is (I'm just amateur IT support for a retirement group) This is just for regular people (not government, or financial, etc.) and they use a VPN but now we taught them about DNS and DoH and they want to know if using both is better or if using both actually decreases security in any way. Thank you.

Comment: These are 2 different solutions for 2 different problems

Comment: My understanding is that VPN provides a secure tunnel for the data flow to the end site but your ISP can still see the end site address, whereas a DoH service supplants your ISP as a resolver and hopefully promises not to sell or analyze which sites you visit. If one layers a VPN connection on top of using a DoH DNS (on an app/service that supports that), then that is in some way better? Or put another way: what would one lose or gain by using both? Thank you

Comment: "but your ISP can still see the end site address" -- how does a ISP do that? I think you are confusing this with "DNS leakage", which isn't solved by DoH, but properly configuring the VPN.

Comment: I'm positive I'm confused...my knowledge base is probably a little thin but, anyway, if a VPN is not split-tunneled (or is indeed configured properly, as you say) then your ISP DNS servers will not see your DNS requests since they go to the VPN servers. True?  VPN provides an encrypted data tunnel and also hides your IP address.  Does it also hide the destination website address from your ISP's designated nameservers, where they could theoretically log it?      Alternatively, encrypting DNS requests with DoH prevents on-path eavesdroppers (and also bypasses the ISP nameservers.  True?)

Comment: So - back to the question – is using both DoH and a VPN "better", kind of like belt PLUS suspenders? What do you tell your family and friends? Again, sorry for my lack of sophistication on this.